# is it possible to get line number of the code from IntelliJ IDEA a SunAwtFrame?

Tags: intellij-idea, autohotkey

I was able to get the line number from some other editors by using autohotkey command A_CaretX and A_CaretY. But not from IntelliJ IDEA a SunAwtFrame. Is there a way to do it? (BTW i want use it inside: https://github.com/sl5net/Magnifier )

Comment: No, apparently this API is very limited only to the standard Windows text controls, I've checked it with various apps and it has worked only in Notepad. Doesn't work in Sublime Text and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: maybe it would work with an intellij plugin?
Dmitry Batrak 12 Mar 2018 at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188042:
"... in your plugin ...
VisualPosition pos = editor.getCaretModel (). GetVisualPosition ();
Point xy = editor.visualPositionToXY (pos); "
So I want to read on here next: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html